# Displaying parameters of method in a textview or toast

Tags: android, parameters, boolean, int, toast

Hey guys i cannot figure out the logic behind why my code is not working, apparently I am not allowed to print out these values in this way.  I cannot display the values of v1,v2,v3 or v4 into a toast or a textfield, but i can display strings.  Am i calling these values wrong?
If you need  me to post more code let me know.

```
testWheelValue(R.id.passw_1, v1);
            testWheelValue(R.id.passw_2, v2);
            testWheelValue(R.id.passw_3, v3);
            testWheelValue(R.id.passw_4, v4);
            testpins = v1 + v2 + v3 + v4;
            text.setText(testpins);
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), testpins,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


private boolean testWheelValue(int id, int value) {
        return getWheel(id).getCurrentItem() == value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v1`, `v2`, `v3`, and `v4` are of type `int`, so the compile recognizes them as resource IDs. Try this:

```
text.setText(String.valueOf(testpins));
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!   I dont display the values im looking for, but my app no longer force closes.